# Test whether the mean value differs significantly from the certified value

Tags: t-test, mean, standard-deviation

[image]

The table shows the results (% Ti) of alloy samples containing different certified amounts of titanium and I am asked to for each alloy, test whether the mean value differs significantly from the certified value.

I am unsure of which T-test to use for this problem. How do I determine which T-test to use in this case?

Thank you!